# mssql Is it possible to query db function?

Tags: sql-server-2012

Is it possible to create a db view that will query a db function?

```
select value from db_function(passing some parameters..)
```

Comment: why can't you try it?

Comment: I tried, i am getting Msg 208, Level 16, State 3, Line 39
Invalid object name 'dbo.SP_GET_INFO'.

Comment: Then your function doesn't exist, or isn't named that...

Comment: @user648026 The name `SP_GET_INFO` points to a *stored procedure* (the `SP_`... - btw: One **should not use the prefix `sp_`, this is reserved!** ). The result of a SP is not so easy to retrieve. The only way is `INSERT INTO SomeTableWithFittingStructure EXEC dbo.SP_GET_INFO`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an (inline!) table valued function is easy. Check it out:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestFunction(@StartOfName VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT * FROM sys.objects AS o WHERE o.name LIKE @StartOfName + '%';
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.TestFunction('m');
GO
DROP FUNCTION dbo.TestFunction;
```

This will return all objects, where the name starts with 'm'.

Such a TVF can be used like a table, can be joined into a select with `APPLY`.

The `VIEW` you want to create can use this function quite as easily as any other `VIEW` or physical table.